# AS3 Key Down event listener doesn't work?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to OOP programming with AS3,
I'm trying to create a listener that will respond when keys are pressed..

It worked fine when I just typed it in the timeline, but now when it's on it's own package it doesn't respond at all, what am I doing wrong?

```
package{
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class PlayerController extends Sprite{
        public function PlayerController(){
            addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,onButDown);
        }
        function onButDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
            trace("Key Down");
        }
    }

}
```

And in the main class I have this:

```
var pc:PlayerController = new PlayerController();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here may be that the instance of PlayerController has not received focus (and never will since it doesn't look like you're adding it to the display list). If an object does not have focus, it cannot receive keyboard events.

One solution would be to pass a reference to `stage` in your constructor and then add the event listener to that instead:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class PlayerController extends Sprite{
        public function PlayerController($stageRef:Stage){
            $stageRef.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,onButDown);
        }
        function onButDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
            trace("Key Down");
        }
    }

}
```

Then, in your main app:

```
var pc:PlayerController = new PlayerController(stage);
```

Edit to add: this is assuming `stage` is not `null`. You would need to make sure of that before you instantiate `PlayerController` in this manner.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work just like I wanted it to :) , by the way it's alright I wrote this right? : public function PlayerController(stage:Stage)

Comment: That will work, but Sprite already has a public property `stage` so for the scope of the constructor, you're overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you're supposed to put all event listeners and the functions they call for in the main class. That is all.

Comment: I just tried to put it in the main class too, it just won't work.. do you see anything wrong in the current code?